# Finding the nearest polygon to the given points

Tags: python, r, arcgis, qgis

I need to join a nearest polygon (in total 1435 polygons) to given points (945) (I need to choose 945 closest polygons).
Even though, procedure sounds quite straightforward, a twist is that my points are assigned with an ordinal number. Each point need to be assigned with an unique polygon, meaning that  if, for example, points with ordinal numbers 12 and 20 are closest to the polygon x, point 12 should be assigned with the polygon x and point 20 must be assigned with another polygon, closest to this point. How this can be solved in R, Python, QGIS or ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: R `sf::st_nearest()`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can make pairings by minimizing total distance sum between the pairs by applying assignment problem to the distance matrix. `df_polygon` is `sf` object with polygon geometry and `df_point` is `sf` object with point geometry:

```
d <- sf::st_distance(df_polygon, df_point, which = "Great Circle")
res <- RcppHungarian::HungarianSolver(d)
cost <- res$cost
pairs <- res$pairs[res$pairs[, 2] > 0,]
```